# How to submit a cat command to a cluster using qsub and use the pipe correctly

Tags: bash, unix, cluster-computing, cat, qsub

I want to submit several "cat jobs" on the fly to a cluster using qsub. Currently I'm concatenating several files with cat to a single one at the end (using `> output_file`) at the end of the command.
The problem is that qsub takes the > output_file from the command as part of the qsub, putting there the log of the job instead of the cat output.

```
qsub -b y -cwd -q bigmem cmd1
```

where `cmd1` looks like:

```
cat file1 file2 filen > output_file
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to submit file1 and file2 as a single job script file via qsub?

Comment: No, I want to concatenate all the file (file 1 to file n) using cat and store it in another file. I have to do this hundreds of times with huge files. That's why I use the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a job is running via pbs, stdout is redirected to the output file of the job, so the way to do this is to write a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat file1 file2 ... filen
```

You don't need to redirect the output to a file because the mom daemon will do that for you in setting up the job, you just need to specify the output file you desire using -o. For example, if you named the above script script.sh (make sure it is executable) you'd submit:

`qsub script.sh -b y -q bigmem -o output_file`

Comment: The whole point of `cat` is that it concatenates many files. It just happens to be a common usage of `cat` to print the contents of a single file to `stdout`. Your command should therefore be `cat file1 file2 ... filen`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to dbeer's answer, if your code is disposable, you can use `echo`:

```
echo "cat file1 file2 ... filen > outfile" | qsub -cwd <options>
```